# Add button to opened app via Linking on React Native App

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I have a case on react native app development :

- The app opens an external app (eg. Facebook App)
- When Facebook App was opened, I need to add a floating button or whatever to Facebook App, it will be used for back to my application
- When that button clicked, it will trigger a function from my react native app

Is it possible ?

What I tried so far is trying to open the app inside a View with WebView and the button that I wanted, but the WebView opens www.facebook.com instead of Facebook App installed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this module to open other native apps.

https://github.com/FiberJW/react-native-app-link

`but as you wanted to place a button that's not possible` because if you open other apps `then control is no longer available in your app to handle that button` in the app which is open now, `Webview will always open a web URL, not a native app.`

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response. I ever see an application that opens other apps with additional components, eg https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lkstudio.uchannel. It opens youtube with some additional components. But when I press app overview button from youtube and back again to youtube, the button disappears. I don't know how to make such like that in react native nor native android